# How to create an isolated list of attributes for a python object?

Tags: python-3.x, object, attributes

I have a python object called `my_obj` that has many attributes called *attr1, attr2, attr3, ...*. **represented as strings**.

I would like to create a list of these attributes in the following pattern:

```
attr_list = [my_obj.attr1, my_obj.attr2, my_obj.attr3]
```

**where each element of the list is an object rather than a string** *using a for loop in which elements are added one at a time*.

I don't know how to convert strings into object before appending them to the list consecutively.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in function that does what you need, off-the-shelf, in Python 3: `getattr`

Official doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a
> string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
> the result is the value of that attribute.

We could use `getattr` this way to tackle your problem:

```
attr_names = ["attr1", "attr2", "attr3"]
attr_list = []

for name in attr_names:
    attr = getattr(my_obj, name)
    attr_list.append(attr)
```

Answer (score 1):

a cleaner way could be

```
attr_list=[getattr(my_obj,name)for name in attr_names]
```